# (onedefinitionrule) breaks one-definition rule

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

There are two tags for the C/C++ one-definition rule:

- [onedefinitionrule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onedefinitionrule)
- [odr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odr)

This is ironic and should be fixed, I think. (There aren't many questions using either tag, but I think it's probably still a useful concept for tagging.)

What's the procedure for synonymizing tags? All I know is that tag-related meta questions need puns in the title.

Comment: Proposal: synonmize onedefinitionrule with odr.

Comment: @Makoto Yes, sorry, that's what I meant to propose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[one-definition-rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/one-definition-rule) is now the target tag (with the excerpt from the previous [odr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odr) as it was more comprehensive) for [onedefinitionrule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onedefinitionrule) and [odr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odr).